# How to show related category name on product page in magento

Tags: javascript, php, wamp, magento-1.8

I want to display related categories in product page.

My product contain cat A and related product cat is cat B, cat C and cat D.

Answer (score 0):

See if this could help you,

Let's say that you already have the current category in the variable $category.
This piece of code should give you all the (active) category siblings.

```
$siblings = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$siblings->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $category->getParentId()) //siblings have the same parent as the current category
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//get only active categories
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq'=>$category->getId()))//exclude current category
        ->addAttributeToSort('position');//sort by position
```

Now you can loop through the siblings and list them:

```
<?php foreach ($siblings as $sibling): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $sibling->getUrl();?>"><?php echo $sibling->getName();?></a><br />
<?php endforeach;?>
```

References: 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/how-to-show-category-siblings